# data-ui-toggle within Form Tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toggle

I am using Angular, and have a data-ui-toggle within a form tag:

```
<a href="" data-ng-click="NewForm=!NewForm">Click for New Form</a>
<form class="custom" name="NewForm" ng-submit="save()" novalidate data-ui-toggle="NewForm">
```

The problem is that the NewForm is showing when the page is loaded, then when you click "Click for New Form" the form toggles away.

I am trying to do the opposite, have not appear on load and then toggle when you click on "Click for New Form"

Answer (score 1):

From the [form directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aform):

> If name attribute is specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.

You are using the same `NewForm` identifier for both, the scope variable which references the FormController which is automatically instantiated by the form directive, and for the ui-toggle flag variable.

This is why `NewForm` scope property is initialized as empty object `{}`, which is a truthy value that tells ui-directive to show the form.
In this example, you need to pick a different name for your form:

```
<form class="custom" name="MyForm" ng-submit="save()" novalidate data-ui-toggle="NewForm">
```